# Dynamic control of mkl-based numpy multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, intel-mkl

I'm using Anaconda's distribution of scientific Python, where numpy is compiled with mkl library.

When attempting multiprocessing, i want to constrain numpy to use a single core.

I know i can set the environment variables 'MKL_NUM_THREADS', 'NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS' and 'OMP_NUM_THREADS' to '1' (using os.environ). However, this will cause numpy to use a single core all around my code, and i want to be able to control that dynamically.

I've encountered Python's 'mkl' package (distributed as part of Anaconda), in which the function "set_num_threads(n)" exists. I tried it, but it leads to weird behavior - for linear algebra operations, it seems large enough matrices causes numpy to resume multithreading.

Can anyone suggest a solution/lead/anything regarding dynamic control of numpy/mkl multithreading?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

To dynamically control MKL or other BLAS libraries (OpenBLAS, Blis) threads from python you can use the [`threadpoolctl`](https://github.com/joblib/threadpoolctl) module.

Install it using pip

```
pip install threadpoolctl
```

**For Example:-**

Considering your NumPy installation is linked against some BLAS library (MKL, OpenBLAS, Blis). This will dynamically set threads to 1 for your BLAS runtime.

```
import threadpoolctl
import numpy as np

A = np.random.random((10**4))
B = np.random.random((10**4))

with threadpoolctl.threadpool_limits(limits=1, user_api="blas"):
    # MKL threads will be limited to 1 inside this block
    np.dot(A, B)
```

For further reference: https://github.com/joblib/threadpoolctl#usage